# Sequelize afterFind hook in eager loading

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've two models User,Profile

I use eager loading to fetch user and it's profile.
But i need to attach image file names of every profile as an array to profile.
So when i want to fetch a profile independently, i can use `FS.readDirSync` to find profile files list and attach it to the Object as an array.
Is possible to do this in `AfterFind` hook in `Sequelize` and is it working in eager loading?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to store the file paths in the db with the user ? Or in a table named "medias" for example ? Mixing db query and file system query seems a bit weird to me

Comment: Yep, But in my opinion managing ```symlinks``` is more painful. :)))

Comment: It seems i should use something like ```OwnCloud``` to manage files painless.

Comment: There is plenty of solutions, like Google Cloud or AWS S3, which will handle files, but even with those you should keep a model referencing those items in your db : a db call (especially with a join) will always be faster than an API query to your storage provider.

Comment: Yes, I did install ```OwnCloud``` and use ```js-owncloud-client``` to interact with it. I do upload profile photos in memory with ```Multer``` then transfer it to ```OwnCloud``` and save file names in Profile model table in an array field. But still ```symlinks``` is my concern. If i use direct share links of files then how can manage link changes. If i download files first and then send them to clients in requests there's overload. hmmm

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by symlink. For me filename should not change. The solution I see is to generate a unique id for each media, using it as filename and id in table « Media ». Then in your media table, you could add any info needed (to handle different urls, or name change etc).

Comment: ```Symlink``` (Symbolic Link) in ```Unix``` means shortcut. Yes file names are unique but my concern is changing share-links in cloud not file names. So it seems i should keep share-links and change them when change.

Comment: I know what symlinks are in unix, but I still dont understand why they are involved in there ^^ If you use your initial solution and read the content of the file system to find your user profile picture, you still need to know where to look ?

Comment: Yes, you right.